# Arranging different data points by date in R?

Tags: r, excel, rstudio

I'm quite new to R. Let me explain my situation clearly. I have excel files of data collected in time increments.  The first column is the time collected.  The second is the value.  This data extends for quite a few years, so there is a lot of it across different files.

I would like to plot these values against time, but the files have gaps.  Data wasn't recorded all of the time in each file, occasionally missing days or weeks.  My files end up being inconsistent,

with one looking like this:

```
2/10/11   430....
2/11/11   437....
4/6/11    309....
```

and the other looking like this:

```
2/10/11  456....
2/13/11  333....
2/14/11  287....
and so on...
```

How can I space these points appropriately along the x axis, so that they are not all pushed together?

Comment: Did you convert those values to proper "Date" values in R? Or did they import as factors? What plotting command did you try exactly?

Comment: I attempted to format the values, such that format = "%m/%d/%Y".  I believe this is on the right track.

Comment: Well, it appears your data uses "%m/%d/%y", but assuming your values are either Date values or POSIX(ct,lt) values, then R should do a reasonable job of plotting them like dates should be plotted.

Comment: That's great! Thanks, certainly this has been slow going for me.  I appreciate the affirmation.